# Why PDF exported from Report Viewer opens in different zoom size in Adobe Reader

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have 16 Reports in my current application. when I export the reports
 through Export drop down menu to PDF file, it saves to my local disk.
 But when I open the PDF through Adobe Acrobat Reader it opens it with
 a different zoom size for each report. Why I am getting this kind of
 behavior.

Can I set a default zoom size for all the generated PDF
 dynamically ??

Comment: The zoom is managed by the PDF viewer application you are using. Reporting Services is not involved.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin I was also suspecting the same thing...Thank you very much...you should have say these comment in answer section...once i get 15 reputation..i will mark it as answer...

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Can you provide any link as a justification or proof..as i need it to show somewhere

Comment: No problem, I will prepare an answer with an official source

Comment: @SébastienSevrin will wait for your answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the zoom level of generated PDFs in Reporting Services.
The zoom is managed by the viewer application, which is Adobe Acrobat Reader in your case.

There is no details about it in the documentation because this feature does not exist, but here is a link to a question on MSDN forums where somebody from Microsoft confirms that there are no ways of doing it:

- [export SSRS report to pdf / controlling zoom](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6a1b4df1-ca32-458f-a1e0-1c631c60e0b1/export-ssrs-report-to-pdf-controlling-zoom)

Answer (score 1):

right click on report and
1) go to report properties

[image]

after that you set height and width  as per your requirement

[image]

Comment: I have same configuration for all the reports...all have same width and height, Margins...

Comment: In acrobat reader, for some reports it's opening with this option as highlighted for the first time "**Fit one full page to window**" while for the rest "**Fit to window width and enable scrolling**" is highlighted for the first time.

Comment: @devgal its not possible in Report at  application level